# Merge two Lists of same type with diff values and avoid duplicates

Tags: c#, .net, list, linq, c#-4.0

I have two lists of same type with different key value pairs, 
List1 has "isPermanent = true" and List2 has false value and also
List1 has an extra key "nextVacationDate".

Im trying to do union of these as below but im afraid I will still get the duplicates because of different values. I need to merge both lists in to one list and order by List1 first (Permanent employees first)..is there a better way to do this using LINQ?

```
public newList1 List1(string abcd)
    {
            var result = serviceMethod1(abcd);
            var newList1 = new List<emp>();
            if (result == null) return null;

            newList.AddRange(
                result.Select(x => new Model
                {
                    firstName = x.FName,
                    secondName = x.SName,
                    address = x.Address,
                    employeeId = x.EmpId,
                    isPermanent = true,
                    nextVacationDate =x.VacDt,
                    salary = x.Bsalary
                }));

            return newList1;


    }

    public newList2 List2(string defg)
    {
        var result = serviceMethod2(defg);
        var newList2 = new List<emp>();
        if (result == null) return null;

        newList.AddRange(
            result.Select(x => new Model
            {
                firstName = x.FName,
                secondName = x.SName,
                address = x.Address,
                employeeId = x.EmpId,
                isPermanent = false,
                salary = x.Bsalary
            }));

        return newList2;


    }
    private List<emp> EmployyeList(List<emp> newList1, List<emp> newList2)
    {
        var sortedEmpList1 = newList1.OrderBy(i => i.Fname);
        var sortedEmpList2 = newList2.OrderBy(i => i.Fname);

        List<MeterModel> combinedList = newList1.Union(newList2) as List<emp>;

        return combinedList;
    }
```

Comment: If this flag is _really not important_ for equality you may want to implement `IEquatable<Model>` on your `Model` class and then use `newList1.Union(newList2)`

Comment: You say `List1` has an extra key `isPermanent` but it doesn't - did you mean `nextVacationDate`? Also, since they are both `new Model` (should that be `new emp`?), it can't be an extra key, just that `List1` has the key valued. I think what you want is the Linq extension method `.DistinctBy`. Then you can do `.OrderBy(i => new { !i.isPermanent, i.Fname })`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter the 2nd list to avoid duplicates:

```
newList1.Union(newList2.Where(emp2 => !newList1.Any(emp1 => emp1.employeeId == emp2.employeeId)))
```